# Clojure Spec and destructuring?

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

Not sure how to write a Spec to check the destructured arguments to a function.

If I have this simple function:

```
(defn make-name [[first last]]
  (str first " " last))
```

And I write this Spec for the argument:

```
(s/def ::vstring2 (s/coll-of string? :kind vector? :count 2 :distinct false))
```

It works correctly:

```
(s/conform ::vstring2 ["Rich" "Hickey"])
=> ["Rich" "Hickey"]
```

But when I try to apply it to the function like so:

```
(s/fdef make-name
        :args ::vstring2
        :ret string?)
```

It blows up:

```
(stest/check `make-name)
=>
({:spec #object[clojure.spec.alpha$fspec_impl$reify__2451
                0x7dd4c5ac
                "clojure.spec.alpha$fspec_impl$reify__2451@7dd4c5ac"],
  :clojure.spec.test.check/ret {:result #error{:cause "Wrong number of args (2) passed to: roster/make-name",

(...)
```

How do I write the function Spec using `::vstring2`? Or do I?

Thank you.

Comment: You may also want to look at `s/tuple` instead of using vector: https://clojure.org/guides/spec#_collections

Comment: `s/tuple` was helpful and I'm using it. Thank you @JurajMartinka.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to specify another spec for your function's arguments e.g. using `s/cat`:

```
(s/fdef make-name
  :args (s/cat :arg1 ::vstring2)
  :ret string?)
```

In your example, the `:args` spec is expecting two arguments because your `::vstring2` spec is a collection expecting two strings. With this change, the function `:args` spec knows that it only takes *one* argument which should conform to `::vstring2`.

There are more function spec examples [here](https://www.clojure.org/guides/spec#_spec_ing_functions) and [here](https://blog.taylorwood.io/2017/10/15/fspec.html).

Comment: Thank you for helping me (again!), Taylor. I had earlier viewed both of the examples you cited but didn't see anything that led me to think of adding the `:arg1` bit.